# How to use Regex use regex to restrict input

Tags: .net, regex

I need to use Regex class ( System.Text.RegularExpressions) to check that one field should only contain values in (`>`, `<`,`<=`, `>=`, `=`).
How do I do the validation if the field contains only those values (using Regex)?

Comment: That should be pretty easy. But have you gave a try as it ?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about how to put the regular expression

Comment: If by a "field" you mean a "full string", you can use `Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(?:[<>]=|[<>=])$")`

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just [use this regex:](https://regex101.com/r/iC7dT7/4)    `^([><=]|<=|>=)$`

use start and end of string anchors to limit the pattern to the whole string, use `[><=]` character class to allow a *single* `<` or `>` or `=`, then `|` alternation to check for the *sequences* `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: Damn ! Why didn't I thought of simpler way. Strange enough it's taking more steps than my complicated one.

Comment: cuz of the longer input string - i put some invalid values in there to make sure...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also try with `^(?=[<>=])[<>]?=?$`

- `[<>]?` matches optional `<` and `>` thus matching `=` if none of them are present.
- `=?` matches optional `=` thus matching `<` or `>`
- If one from both is present it will match `<=` or `>=`
- `(?=[<>=])` positive lookahead for either of these characters makes sure it's not empty.
- `^` and `$` makes sure that whole string is a match.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC7dT7/2)**

Comment: Actually, I must clarify, only one of the operators are allowed in the field , at a time

Comment: @santubangalore: Yes, did you checked the demo ? `>=` is counted as one operator right ?